# Document extraction fails in publish log after uploading using BIM 360 API

Tags: autodesk-bim360

I am trying to upload the files using document management API. The file gets uploaded but fails with "We couldn't process the following document. Extraction failed"  error message.

I tried uploading image,PDF etc. But the same file gets extracted and published successfully when done manually through UI

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just tested with [this sample](https://forgedatamanagement.herokuapp.com/) ([source code here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/data.management-csharp-sample/blob/master/forgeSample/Controllers/DataManagementController.cs#L324)) and worked fine.

[image]